# Using stackviews programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uistackview

I have created a custom `UIView` and inside of the view I'm trying to add a few UI elements using `UIStackView`.

Inside of IB I added a view and then set the custom class to be my custom UIView.

The `UIStackView` does not appear to be constrained to the `UIView` I added it to, instead the `UIStackView` appears anchored to the origin. Also, I can only see it in the debug view hierarchy. Its not actually showing any of the lables or button, I just see a dashed grey box.[image]

[image]

Here is the custom view I created

```
import UIKit

class ParameterControl: UIView {

private var name : UILabel!
private var valTf : UITextField!
private var delta : UITextField!
private var stepper : UIStepper!
private var button : UIButton!

init(frame: CGRect, albumCover: String) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    commonInit()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    commonInit()
}

func commonInit(){

    name = UILabel()
    name.text = "Name"
    name.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

    valTf = UITextField.init()
    delta = UITextField.init()
    stepper = UIStepper.init()
    button = UIButton.init()

    let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [valTf, delta, stepper, button])
    stackView.axis = .horizontal
    stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
    stackView.alignment = .fill
    stackView.spacing = 10
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    addSubview(stackView)

    //let viewsDictionary = ["stackView":stackView]
    //let stackView_H = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-20-[stackView]-20-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)
    //let stackView_V = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-30-[stackView]-30-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue:0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)
    //self.addConstraints(stackView_H)
    //self.addConstraints(stackView_V)

}

}
```

Am I using `UIStackView` incorrectly? The goal is to be able to create an array of these views, one for each of my parameters. I don't want to create these views individually in IB.

Comment: You need to add constraints to your stack view to constrain it to its superview (self in your custom class)

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment the constraints in your code and make sure that they are activated on the stack view. It is staying in it's default position and frame because you are not giving it any constraints that tell it to behave otherwise. Also, make sure all of your elements have a valid frame.